# How do I fix my Minecraft PE view?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Minecraft PE screen used to be set up so that when I moved my finger downwards across my screen, my "head" (In MC) moved upwards, and vice-versa; but my Minecraft reset, so now when I move my finger in a direction, it goes that direction, which I'm not used to.  How do I fix it?

Comment: Can almost guarantee in the settings somewhere there is an option called "Invert Y" or "Invert Vertical Movement" - something to that tune.  Try enabling that option.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **settings** and press "touch". There will be a button that says "invert y axis" and press that. then when you move your finger down you will look up and when you move your finger up it will move down.